# Add data to many-to-many relation with one SQL command

Tags: sql, sqlite, many-to-many, sql-insert

I have a basic understanding of SQL databases and I might overlooked something, but I cannot figure out the following problem: there is a many-to-many relationship (for example: users - user_roles - roles). Is it possible to add (new) role to a (new) user with one SQL command (atomic operation)? Currently I use Sqlite.

I am aware of the `SELECT last_insert_rowid();` command and with this and several SQL commands I can achieve what I want. But I want to incorporate it into one command (so the server, in this case Sqlite, can optimize the query, etc.). I have no idea, how it is done in real life (one command vs. several one in one transaction), that´s the root cause of this question.

So far this is what I was able to do:

```
pragma foreign_keys = on;

CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id integer primary key autoincrement,
  user_name text not null unique
);

CREATE TABLE roles (
  role_id integer primary key autoincrement,
  role_name text not null unique
);

CREATE TABLE user_roles (
  user_id integer not null,
  role_id integer not null,
  foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id),
  foreign key (role_id) references roles(role_id),
  primary key (user_id, role_id)
);

insert into users (user_name) values ('Joe');
insert into roles (role_name) values ('admin');

insert into user_roles (user_id, role_id) values (
  (select user_id from users where user_name = 'Joe'),
  (select role_id from roles where role_name = 'admin')
);
```

If both user and role exists (Joe and admin), then it works fine.
But I cannot figure out, how to achieve "add-if-missing-then-return-id" behavior if Joe or admin is mission from database.

Example (both user and role are missing):

```
insert into user_roles (user_id, role_id) values (
  (select user_id from users where user_name = 'Bill'),
  (select role_id from roles where role_name = 'user')
);
```

Result:

```
Execution finished with errors.
Result: NOT NULL constraint failed: user_roles.user_id
```

Comment: Instead of INSERT use INSERT OR IGNORE and your code is fine.

Comment: If I modify INSERT to INSERT OR IGNORE, nothing happens. (Execution finished without errors. Result: query executed successfully. Took 0ms, 0 rows affected)

Comment: If you want 1 statement to cover all cases then it is not possible. Execute 3 separate statements with INSERT OR IGNORE like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a92d49a51bda1fe1daafba4e0dda1582

Comment: It is possible via [view](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) and ['instead of' trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [create view](https://sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) from `user_roles` table:

```
CREATE VIEW user_roles_view AS
  SELECT
    U.user_name, R.role_name
  FROM user_roles AS UR
    INNER JOIN users AS U ON u.user_id = UR.user_id
    INNER JOIN roles AS R ON r.role_id = UR.role_id;
```

Views in SQLite are read-only unless you create an [INSTEAD OF trigger](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#instead_of_trigger) on it. This way you can specify a command or sequence of commands that are executed when the view is modified using `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statement. For `INSERT` it could go like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_roles_view_insert INSTEAD OF INSERT ON user_roles_view
BEGIN
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users (user_name) VALUES (NEW.user_name);
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO roles (role_name) VALUES (NEW.role_name);
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO user_roles (user_id, role_id) VALUES (
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_name = NEW.user_name),
    (SELECT role_id FROM roles WHERE role_name = NEW.role_name)
  );
END;
```

Note the usage of `INSERT OR IGNORE` to prevent inserting duplicate values into all of the three tables. Here's how you would insert values via the view:

```
INSERT INTO user_roles_view VALUES ('Joe', 'admin');
-- The above statement creates:
--   a row (1, 'Joe') in table users,
--   a row (1, 'admin) in table roles,
--   a row (1, 1) in table user_roles.

INSERT INTO user_roles_view VALUES ('Joe', 'admin');
-- The above statement doesn't add any additional records, because all appropriate records
-- already exist.

INSERT INTO user_roles_view VALUES ('Joe', 'system');
-- The above statement creates:
--   a row (2, 'system') in table roles,
--   a row (1, 2) in table user_roles.

INSERT INTO user_roles_view VALUES ('Alice', 'admin'), ('Bob', 'system');
-- The above statement creates:
--   a row (2, 'Alice') in table users,
--   a row (3, 'Bob') in table users,
--   a row (2, 1) in table user_roles,
--   a row (3, 2) in table user_roles
```

All of the above statements produce the following output from user_roles_view (`SELECT * FROM user_roles_view`):

| user_name | role_name |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | admin |
| Joe | system |
| Alice | admin |
| Bob | system |

Comment: It works perfectly [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=22a95ee7b60d0839afa0106df911d073). Thank you!
How is this done in production environment? The client sends several SQL commands?

Comment: @Kiki What do you mean by production environment? The solution I demonstrated is perfectly viable in production. If the requirement for managing users and roles is a part of business logic, I'd probably move the functionality out of the database trigger to business logic layer.