# Sqlite column with repetitive values

Tags: python, database, sqlite, duplicates, database-performance

Let's say the column `a` of a SQLite DB is **very repetitive with always the same 4 values**. Other values might appear later, but there will be less than 1000 different values.

```python
VALUES = ["hello world", "it's a shame to store this str many times", "bye bye", "abc"]

import sqlite3, random
db = sqlite3.connect('repetitive1.db')
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a TEXT);")
for i in range(1000 * 1000):
    db.execute("INSERT INTO data (a) VALUES (?)", (random.choice(VALUES),))
db.commit()
```

Here the DB is 24 MB large for one million items, i.e. 24 bytes on average.

It's a bit a shame to re-store all the strings many times, since it's always the same values **again and again**. Of course a solution would be to use an ID = 0, 1, 2, 3 (up to 1000 later) for the repetitive values, and only store the integer IDs:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('repetitive2.db')
db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, a INT);")
for i in range(1000*1000):
    db.execute("INSERT INTO data (a) VALUES (?)", (random.randint(0, 3),))
db.commit()
```

Gain: the DB is only 9 MB, i.e. 9 bytes per row on average, which is much better.

But the drawback is that we have to do this manually:

- maintain **another table** with a correspondence between IDs and strings,
- detect when a new value (never seen before) appears, give it a new ID, etc.
- if rows are removed and finally a string no longer appears anywhere, we might want to do some cleanup and remove its ID from this second table
- etc.

This is possible and not very difficult, but I've noticed along the years that SQLite often has clever optimizations / good tricks for similar things.

**Question:** is there a way to let SQLite do everything automatically? i.e. set a mode in which, internally, SQLite will do its best to deduplicate data in a column, for example by using IDs for this column instead of storing the same string again and again? (without having to maintain anything ourselves?)

Comment: SQLite is very lightweight database, and this "feature" is far beyond its capabilities. It doesn't support the scenario you describe out-of-the-box. It supports some features that let you achieve your goal with a little help. See this recent question for reference: [Add data to many-to-many relation with one SQL command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343126/add-data-to-many-to-many-relation-with-one-sql-command/65357904).

Comment: The linked view + triggers technique is a decent wait to approach the task, yeah.

Comment: @Shawn I'm currently reading it, as well as the live "fiddle" example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=22a95ee7b60d0839afa0106df911d073, but I don't see exactly for now how to apply a similar technique in my use case. If you have the time, could you outline the method in an answer with the main queries?

Comment: @PeterWolf I read the linked question but as it's rather new for me, I'm unsure about the method. If you have a few minutes, do you think you could show the main queries to do this?

Comment: Here is starting point @PeterWolf: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=132fed913405c491d02f90415e05eac8 but I don't see how to link the table `words` containing the 4 words (that will eventually grow until max 1000 items), and the table `data` containing 1 million of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is very similar to [Add data to many-to-many relation with one SQL command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343126/add-data-to-many-to-many-relation-with-one-sql-command/65357904), but it also discusses further aspect - automatic clean-up of unused entities.

> Is there a way to let SQLite do everything automatically? ... (without having to maintain anything ourselves)

No. You basically want to insert rows in the base table and referenced table if it doesn't exist yet, while specifying the reference by value rather than its [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). That in fact isn't a straightforward task in other RDBMSes as well. Some of them support:

- Stored procedures
- [Multitable inserts](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/multitable-inserts)
- [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql)
- [RETURNING clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dml-returning.html)
- Writable (updatable) views
- `INSTEAD OF` triggers on views

From the above list SQLite only supports `INSTEAD OF` triggers. Here's how it applies to your use case (I have adopted table `words` from your db<>fiddle mentioned in comments under the question and renamed its column `a` to `value`):

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

CREATE TABLE words(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  value TEXT
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_words_value ON words(value);

CREATE TABLE data(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  word_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (word_id) REFERENCES words(id)
);

CREATE VIEW data_view AS
SELECT d.id, w.value FROM data AS d INNER JOIN words AS w on w.id = d.word_id;

CREATE TRIGGER data_view_insert INSTEAD OF INSERT ON data_view
BEGIN
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO words(value) VALUES (NEW.value);
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(word_id) VALUES(
    (SELECT id FROM words WHERE value = NEW.value)
  );
END;

INSERT INTO data_view (value) VALUES
  ('random1'),
  ('random2'),
  ('random3'),
  ('random1'),
  ('random3'),
  ('random4');
```

The `INSERT` statement produced this content of table `words`:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | random1 |
| 2 | random2 |
| 3 | random3 |
| 4 | random4 |

and `data_view`:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | random1 |
| 2 | random2 |
| 3 | random3 |
| 4 | random1 |
| 5 | random3 |
| 6 | random4 |

To support deleting row from `data` with automatic clean-up of unused values in `words` you can add `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger on `data_view`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER data_view_delete INSTEAD OF DELETE ON data_view
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM data
    WHERE id = OLD.id;
  DELETE FROM words
    WHERE value = OLD.value AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM data_view WHERE value = OLD.value);
END;
```

Its first statement deletes a row in table `data` and the second deletes the referenced value from `words`, if it isn't referenced by other rows in table `data`. Similarly to `INSERT`, you delete rows from table `data` indirectly via `data_view`:

```
-- delete one 'random2' and 'random4' value data
DELETE FROM data_view WHERE id IN (2, 4);
```

That results in `words`:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | random1 |
| 3 | random3 |
| 4 | random4 |

As you can see the `'random2'` value was deleted, because it was referenced only once in `data`, and `'random4'` value was kept, because there was another reference in table `data` (`data_view`):

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | random1 |
| 3 | random3 |
| 5 | random3 |
| 6 | random4 |

Here's [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6e7ad700e18efb1152b676220b66b32d) to play with.

Comment: Note: if we remove `FOREIGN KEY (word_id) REFERENCES words(id)` in the creation of `data` table, it does not change anything in terms of DB size and speed, see my answer below. For what is this `FOREIGN KEY` really useful here?

Comment: @Basj Foreign keys are here to ensure referential integrity.  They can be [completely disabled](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) using `PRAGMA` command. In that case FK only annotates relationship between the two tables. Foreign keys are disabled by default due to backwards compatibility with older versions of SQLite.

Comment: Do you know @PeterWolf if the two queries `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO (...)` and `INSERT INTO data ...` can be grouped in one single query or at least one `db.execute(...)`, at the end of [this code]?(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408219/sqlite-column-with-repetitive-values/65420615#65420615) (in the "Same idea, but without a view" part)

Comment: @Basj SQLite doesn't support inserting data into multiple tables using single statement. That's what the view and trigger simulate. From [`execute`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) documentation: *If you try to execute more than one statement with it, it will raise a Warning*. I guess that suggested [`executescript`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript)  isn't an option for you because it does explicit `COMMIT` and doesn't support parameter binding.

Answer (score 0):

Full credit to @PeterWolf for his excellent answer, here is a slightly modified version and ready-to-run code:

```
import sqlite3, random
VALUES = ["hello world", "it's a shame to store this str many times", "bye bye", "abc"]
db = sqlite3.connect('repetitive3.db')
db.executescript("""CREATE TABLE words(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT UNIQUE);
CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, word_id INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE VIEW data_view AS SELECT d.id, w.value FROM data AS d INNER JOIN words AS w on w.id = d.word_id;
CREATE TRIGGER data_view_insert INSTEAD OF INSERT ON data_view
BEGIN
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO words(value) VALUES(NEW.value);
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO data(word_id) VALUES((SELECT id FROM words WHERE value = NEW.value));
END;""")
for i in range(1000*1000):
    db.execute("INSERT INTO data_view (value) VALUES (?)", (random.choice(VALUES),))
print(list(db.execute("SELECT * FROM words")))
print(list(db.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 105")))
print(list(db.execute("SELECT * FROM data_view WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 105")))
```

Minor modifications (the result is the same: 9 MB only database size)

- there is here no index on table `words`, but only the `UNIQUE` keyword for `value`, that ensures that `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO` falls into `IGNORE` if the value already exists
- no FOREIGN KEY used

---

Same idea, but without a view:

```
db.execute('CREATE TABLE words(value TEXT UNIQUE);')
db.execute('CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, word_id INTEGER NOT NULL);')
for i in range(1000*1000):
    v = random.choice(VALUES)
    db.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO words(value) VALUES(?);", (v,))
    db.execute("INSERT INTO data(word_id) VALUES ((SELECT rowid FROM words WHERE value = ?));", (v,))
searched_word = 'hello world'
print(list(db.execute("SELECT id, word_id FROM data WHERE id BETWEEN 100 AND 120 AND word_id = (SELECT rowid FROM words WHERE value = ?)", (searched_word,))))
```